# Approximate pi using finitie series

Tags: matlab, while-loop

Given the equation to approximate `pi`

[image: Here is the equation to approximate pi]

I need to the number of terms (`n`) that are needed to obtain an approximation that is within `10^(-12)` of the actual value of `pi`. The code I have to find the `n` looks like this:

[image: ]]

[image: code to find n]

The `while` loop statement I have seems to never end, so I feel like my code must be wrong.

Comment: It never ends because you're not incrementing `n` (count of approximation series terms) inside your `while true` loop.

Comment: I reverted some of your edits, because they included parts of the answer. Note that using the Matlab debugger may be useful to find such a mistakes yourself. May I ask you to include code as text instead of an image in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines (transcribed from your image), incrementing the number of approximation terms `n` **inside** your infinite `while` loop:

```
s = 1
n = 1
while true
    s = abs(pi - approximate_pi(n))
    if s <= 0.001
        break
    end
    n = n + 1
end
```

On a related note, this calculation is a little bit pointless if you know the value of `pi` beforehand. Termination condition **should** be on the absolute magnitude of the `n-th` term.

The way you're doing it makes sense only if you're trying to find out minimum `n` for which your approximation series produces the result within some margin of error.

**Edit**. So, normally you would do it like this:

```
n = 1;
sum_running = 0
sum_target = (pi^2 - 8) / 16;
while true
    sum_running += 1 / ((2*n-1)^2 * (2*n+1)^2);
    if abs(sum_target - sum_running) <= 10e-12
        break
    end
    n += 1;
end
pi_approx = sqrt(16*sum_running + 8)
```

There's no need to keep recalculating `pi` approximation up to `n` terms, for each new `n`. This is has `O(n)` complexity, while your initial solution had `O(n^2)`, so it's much faster for large `n`.

Comment: thank you for the timely response. I just tried to put the n = n + 1 inside the loop, but it still didn't end. Do you think my while loop looks correct? Or, how should I increment n-th term

Comment: The problem could be with the double `sqrt`. Remove the one in the `while` loop (see update).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I added the abs() to the s function part, but my loop still not ends.  n= 1
s = 1
while true
    s = abs(pi - approximate_pi(n))
    if s <= 10^(-12)
        break
    end
    n = n + 1
end

Comment: I've just tested the complete code. It works, it's just slow for `10e-12`. Final `n = 3757`, `pi_approx = 3.14159265358879`. The reason it's slow is because you're calculating the complete sum (`1:n`), for each iteration of `n`. It would be better to just keep adding one term per iteration.

Comment: thank you for your explanations! I got the right n :)